# How to define an array of strings as an environmental parameter/variable in the context-file?

Tags: java, arrays, tomcat, tomcat7

Within Tomcat 7 I can define environmental parameters/variables of specific types like in this context file:

```
<Context>
    <Environment name="test" value="Hello Tomcat!" type="java.lang.String"
    override="false" />
</Context>
```

In Java I can get it like this:

```
(String) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/test"); //"Hello Tomcat!"
```

How can I define an array containing strings as values so I can read it from the context-file? I want to get something like this in my Java program:

```
(String[]) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/my_array");
//{"Hello ", "Tomcat", "!"}
```

Is this possible within Tomcat 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use arrays. The  [Tomcat 7 documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/globalresources.html#Environment_Entries) says:

> The fully qualified Java class name expected by the web application for this environment entry. Must be a legal value for  in the web application deployment descriptor.

And this [JavaEE 7 tutorial about environmental entries](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/env_entry/env_entry.html) says:

> The data type of the environmental entry. The following data types are valid in Java EE 6:
>
> ```
> java.lang.Boolean
> java.lang.Byte
> java.lang.Character
> java.lang.String
> java.lang.Short
> java.lang.Integer
> java.lang.Long
> java.lang.Float
> java.lang.Double
> java.lang.Class
> any enumeration type (i.e. a subclass of java.lang.Enum)
> ```

Of course you can write multiple values in a format of your choice as a String, for example separated by commas:

```
<Environment name="test" value="value1,value2" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />

String[] values = new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/my_array").split(",");
```

You can also use any other format, like JSON. Just make sure it doesn't conflict with the XML syntax.